# IE devices css left:initial and right:1 property not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have following dropdown it is disturb almost in all IE browsers.
html structure is in form of ul li and css code for dropdown

```css
.dropdown{
  width: 25%;
  right: 1px;
  left: initial;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
   z-index: 101;
  overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 190px;
   border-top: none;
   padding: 16px 0px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   border-radius: 4px;
  }
.dropdown li{
    min-height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 6px 24px;
    color: #212121;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
     <li>Received</li>
  <li>Sent</li>
         </ul>
```

Following screenshot will clarify issues in IE browsers.
Existing/Designed UI
[image]

Disturb UI in IE browsers

[image]

Comment: Can you make a working snippet, one that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MrLister Lister  please check working snippet

Comment: I don't see the same thing. The block is to the right of the screen in IE11. What browser and/or compatibility mode are we talking about here?

Comment: windows win8.1 and browsers IE 11

Comment: Do you have an initial setting for "left" ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp

Comment: The default position is static and "Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties." http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @CarolMcKay The OP's example has `position:absolute`